# Can NSubstitute check calls that take an Expression<T>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm trying to validate a call to a method that takes a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T, U>>`, but I'm not able to get NSubstitute to recognize it.

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    void DoThing<TProperty>(TProperty i, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression);
}

// this almost works, but throws AmbiguousArgumentException
myFoo.Received(1).DoThing(Arg.Is(10), Arg.Any<Expression<Func<MyClassType, long>>>());
```

Comment: What's myObj? Can you post its structure?

Comment: How `myObj` is defined should be irrelevant. In my real-world case, `myObj` is implementing an interface that defines `DoThing`. It could be completely empty except for that one method. In my test method, `myObj` is an NSubstitute substitution.

Comment: I'm asking because in my tests, I was unable to reproduce the behavior you're seeing. However, my assumptions regarding the DoThing method signature may be wrong. Can you share the method's definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while trying to figure out why my tests failed but David Tchepak's worked, I realized my original question did not include the fact that the type of the property was generic as well (question has been updated). When I made that change to David's code, I started seeing the same errors as in my original code.

I have found the solution, however:

```
// fails with AmbiguousArgumentException
myObj.Received(1).DoThing(Arg.Is(10), Arg.Any<Expression<Fun<MyClassType, long>>>());

// passes, but doesn't validate first parameter
myObj.Received(1).DoThing(Arg.Any<long>(), Arg.Any<Expression<Fun<MyClassType, long>>>());

// passes, _and_validates first parameter
myObj.Received(1).DoThing(10, Arg.Any<Expression<Fun<MyClassType, long>>>());

// passes, _and_validates first parameter
myObj.Received(1).DoThing(Arg.Is<long>(10), Arg.Any<Expression<Fun<MyClassType, long>>>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes NSubstitute can work with calls that take expressions. The following test passes for me:

```
public class MyClassType {
    public long Property { get; set; }
}
public interface IFoo {
    void DoThing(int i, Expression<Func<MyClassType, long>> expression);
}

[Test]
public void ReceivedWithAnyExpression() {
    var myObj = Substitute.For<IFoo> ();
    myObj.DoThing (10, x => x.Property);
    myObj.Received(1).DoThing(Arg.Is(10), Arg.Any<Expression<Func<MyClassType, long>>>());
}
```

What is the compile error you are getting?

Comment: My mistake. It isn't a compile error (maybe I had a typo before). I'm working on the differences. I'll update my post when I narrow it down to the true problem.

Comment: Your answer ended up helping me find the right answer. Thanks!